# MACSec encryption over PBN?

Tags: encryption, macsec

This came up in a more generic link layer encryption question:

Commodity switches with MACSec hardware offers wirespeed AES-GCM encryption at a fraction of the cost typically associated with layer 2 encryption.

Is it at all possible to extend MACSec (802.1AE) as a point-to-point solution over a provider bridge (802.1AD) or will this break frame integrity?

If Q-in-Q won't work, might it be possible to use some other form of enveloping or low-overhead encapsulation to transport the MACSec encrypted frames through carrier ethernet?

I do realize MACSec is intended for hop-by-hop security, but naturally hop-by-hop encryption becomes a lot less interesting when the networks (and the encryption keys) are managed by a third party such as the communications provider. It is necessary to maintain point-to-point data integrity and security all the way through the provider network, although preferably not at the cost of tunneling and fork lifting the traffic to layer 3 for IPSec encryption.

Even when possible, might there be any good reasons to avoid MACSec for point-to-point encryption, or any other special considerations that should be taken into account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mick Seaman (IEEE 802.1 Interworking TF chair) have written an extensive paper on this exact problem. The paper named "MACSec hops" appear to conclude that it might be possible although, at least in some cases, undesirable to have MACSec frames traverse a PBN or PBBN.

The paper is available here: http://www.ieee802.org/1/files/public/docs2013/ae-seaman-macsec-hops-0213-v02.pdf